# strong parameters doesn't allow to create nested attributes with json. ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models: conference and talks. conference has_many talks and

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :talks, :allow_destroy => true
```

Params i am posting looks like that:

```
{"id"=>"2", "name"=>"rails4444", "tags"=>"ruby, rails, backbone, javascript", "date"=>"2014-02-22", "organizer"=>"BackboneMeetupGroup", "description"=>"conference with cool speakers", "talks"=>{"title"=>"fdsf", "video_url"=>"fdsf"},
```

where i am setting talks as the should be created in the database.

My html looks like that:

```
<input type="text" name="talks[title]" placeholder="Talk Title" />
<input type="text" name="talks[video_url]" placeholder="url" />
```

and when I am updating my conference model with talks it gives me an error:

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Talk(#70154003251480) expected, got Array(#70154000241560)):
  app/controllers/conferences_controller.rb:25:in `update'

my controller looks like that:

```
 def update
    @single = Conference.find params[:id]
    if @single.update_attributes conference_params
      render "conferences/show"
    else
      respond_with @single
    end
  end



  def conference_params
    params.permit(:name, :tags, :date, :organizer, :description, :place, :talks => [:conference_id, :id, :title, :video_url])
  end
```

why do i get ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

As `conference` `has_many` `talks`, you need an array of talks as nested attributes, not a single one.

Your input fields need names like:

```
<input type="text" name="conference[talks_attributes][0][title]" />
```

to work with `accepts_nested_attributes`. The normal way to create those input is to use

```
<%= fields_for :talks do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.text_field :title %>
<% end %>
```

See [Rails Guide on form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

And you need to use `talks_attributes` in `permit` as medBo suggests.

Answer (score 1):

in your `conference_params` method just add `_attributes` to `talks` symbol like this `talks_attributes` so your method becomes :

```
def conference_params
  params.permit(:name, :tags, :date, :organizer, :description, :place, :talks_attributes =>  [:conference_id, :id, :title, :video_url])
end
```

Comment: i tried this, but now talks is Unpermitted parameter.:          Conference Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "conferences".* FROM "conferences" WHERE "conferences"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
Unpermitted parameters: id, created_at, updated_at, color, thumb, talks_num, created_at_formatted, updated_at_formatted, talks, conference

Comment: where come from these color, thumb, talks_num ... i think this is not a related problem ?